# TKiNTER - Como salvar string de Entry()

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu estou com um problema sobre tkinter, não estou conseguindo salvar o valor de uma Entry() em uma variável qualquer, para que assim que possa usar o nome desse arquivo para criar um TXT.

Siga o código:

```
def criarPL ():
    global nome_pl
    def salvar():
        arq = open("{0}.txt".format(nome_pl), "w")
        arq.close()

    janela2 = Tk()
    janela2.title("Criar Playlist")

    bt_salvar = Button(janela2, width=20, text="SALVAR", command=salvar)

    nome_pl = Entry(janela2)
    nome_pl.insert(END, "NOME DA PLAYLIST\n")
    nome_pl.pack()

    nome_pl.place  (x=170, y=2)
    bt_salvar.place(x=2, y=2)

    janela2.geometry("400x27+250+250")
    janela2.mainloop()
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, eu alterei duas coisas:

`arq = open("{0}.txt".format(nome_pl), "w")`

Eu coloquei .get() no final do `nome_pl`, eu dei uma lida e get() serve para literalmente, obter o conteúdo, algo assim. Então ao clicar no "Salvar" o arquivo é gerado com o nome digitado.

`arq = open("{0}.txt".format(nome_pl.get()), "w")`

**E esse:**

Tirei o "NOME DA PLAYLIST\n", por que dava conflito por conta do "\", que é um caractere especial, que não dá para por no nome do arquivo. Sim, eu sei, o nome não será "Nome da Playlist", mas como o texto não some ao clicar ( pelo menos aqui ) e eu não conheço muito o tkinter eu não encontrei uma forma de fazer isso, então eu retirei pra não ter que ficar apagando, mas acho que isso você deve resolver.

`nome_pl.insert(END, "NOME DA PLAYLIST\n")`

`nome_pl.insert(END,'')`

Qualquer dúvida, só comentar.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez haha.

Comment: está rodando aqui

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código que funcionou aqui. Eu inverti a ordem da linha do "pack" e a do "insert", e na função "salvar", usei "nome_pl.get()".

```
def criarPL ():
    global nome_pl
    def salvar():
        arq = open("{0}.txt".format(nome_pl.get()), "w")
        arq.close()

    janela2 = Tk()
    janela2.title("Criar Playlist")

    bt_salvar = Button(janela2, width=20, text="SALVAR", command=salvar)

    nome_pl = Entry(janela2)
    nome_pl.pack()
    nome_pl.insert(0, "NOME DA PLAYLIST")


    nome_pl.place  (x=170, y=2)
    bt_salvar.place(x=2, y=2)

    janela2.geometry("400x27+250+250")
    janela2.mainloop()
```